# Xamarin Essentials App Theme issues with iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

wondering if anyone can shed some light on a issue I seem to be having in Xamarin forms. When I use the Xamarin Essentials App Theme API and use

```
{AppThemeBinding Light=#ffffff, Dark=#000000}
```

on my xaml code it works but when on iOS it does not change the shell navigate and tab bar colours but it does when I change the iOS device appearance from light to dark mode using the device settings menu is there a fix for this as I need the whole app to follow my theme is there a way to stop iOS from taking over and just have it in my app as I just want a toggle for it. I have tried on the application load using

```
Application.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Dark;
```

but it does not seem to affect the navbar and tab bar.

Comment: Could you show someting like this [effect display](https://imgur.com/a/aNg6qHG)？

Comment: Did you set  {AppThemeBinding Light=#ffffff, Dark=#000000}  for the shell BackgroundColor property? It can respond to system theme changes by setting ```Application.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Dark;``` on my side

Comment: It would be much better if you could share some relevant code about how you set the shell navigationbar and tabbar to help us reproduce this issue.

Comment: Hi all, sorry late reply to this but it turns out I had to change some properties in the appshell.xaml then it worked. but the iOS keyboard does not change colour